# Using similar variable names in R, split/subset a large dataframe into multiple smaller ones

Tags: r

I have a dataset with more than 300 variables in the following manner:

## create example data:

```
id <- c('a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
type <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
x_97 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
y_97 <- c('q','w','r','t', 'y', 'i')
z_97 <- c(80,90,70,50,60,40)
x_98 <- c(7,8,9,4,5,6)
y_98 <- c('y', 'i', 'r','t','q','w')
x_99 <- c(4,5,5,6,1,2)
z_99 <- c(20,10,40,50,20,50)
w_99 <- c(8,9,7,4,5,NA)
my.data <- data.frame(id, type, x_97, y_97, z_97, x_98, y_98, x_99, z_99)
```

Please note: _97, _98, _99 are years 1997, 1998 and 1999.

## expected outcome:

I want to split this big data frame into 3 smaller data frames by year on the basis of id and type.

## initial thoughts:

I am creating a list:

```
my.list <- c("_97", "_98", "_99")
```

And now I want to write something like this:

```
newdata97 <- subset(my.data, all variables with the 1st object of my.list)
newdata98 <- subset(my.data, all variables with the 2nd object of my.list)
```

and so on.

## question

1. I am not sure how to achieve the newdata frames as above. Can anyone please help?
2. Moreover, I think there must be a more elegant solution to this with something from apply family. Any idea?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Do you need `lst1 <- lapply(my.list, function(x)  cbind(my.data[1:2], my.data[grep(x, names(my.data))])); names(lst1) <- paste0("newdata", my.list); list2env(lst1, envir = .GlobalEnv)`  Or with `split` `split.default(my.data[-(1:2)], sub(".*_", "", names(my.data)[-(1:2)]))`

Comment: Hi @akrun, thanks a lot for this. The first one does what I need! And is there any way to create all the variables in each data frame? (meaning to have z in the data frame for 1998 too with all values being NA?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use loop through the 'my.list', use `grep` to extract the column names that match the substring in 'my.list', `cbind` with the first two column to create a `list` of `data.frames`

```
lst1 <- lapply(my.list, function(x) cbind(my.data[1:2], 
     my.data[grep(x, names(my.data))]))
```

If there is one of the columns among 'x', 'y', 'z' are missing, then can assign it to `NA`

```
lst1 <-  lapply(lst1, function(x)  {nm1 <- setdiff(paste0(c('x', 'y', 
 'z'),  substring(names(x)[3], 2)), names(x)[-(1:2)]); x[nm1] <- NA; x})
```

---

Or instead of creating columns later, create NA columns in the 'my.data'

```
my.data[setdiff(paste0(rep(c("x_", "y_", "z_"), each = 3), 
       97:99), names(my.data)[-(1:2)])] <- NA
```

and then use `grep` as above into creating a `list` of data.frames

---

Or another option is `split` based on the substring of the column names

```
lst1 <- lapply(split.default(my.data[-(1:2)], 
   sub(".*_", "", names(my.data)[-(1:2)])), function(x) cbind(my.data[1:2], x))
```

It is better to keep it as a `list`, but if we need individual data.frames in the global env, then name the `list` elements and use `list2env` (not recommended though)

```
names(lst1) <- paste0("newdata", substring(my.list, 2))
list2env(lst1, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, Thank you very much. I followed the code where I create the NA columns in the big data and then use the grep code and that's exactly what I needed to do. I also did the split bit and this gives the same thing.. why is it better to keep it in a list?

Comment: @econbuffin2019 1) It is easier to do all the operations in the list. 2)  Having lots of objects in the global env is not a good idea, 3) if you have done all operations on all the objects and want to save the objects, then you may need to bring it back to a list to save each object as a separate file or save it one by one (which is hard when there are more objects)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand your point. Will keep in mind. In this case, I didn't need to do similar operations but I see if I had to, it would be better on the list. Thank you once again.